# EOFException Volley error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I see this question was asked before ([Volley.NoConnectionError : java.io.EOFException 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885953/volley-noconnectionerror-java-io-eofexception-0)) but with not answer.

I have the exact same problem. It works well, just sometime... mainly when I run it the first time I get EOFException.

Here is my Volley request (ignore bad formating):

```
 public void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
    Log.e("TMS", "makeJsonObjectRequest 111 ");
    final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {                       
                    Log.d("TMS", "aaaaaa " +  response.toString());

                    try {

                        jsonResponse = "";
                        String id = null;
                        String naslov = null;
                        String akter = null;
                        String akter_id = null;
                        String slika = null;
                        String izjava = null;
                        String izvor = null;
                        String datum_izjave = null;
                        String tip_ocena = null;
                        String kategorija = null;
                        String status = null;
                        String komentar_istinomera = null;
                        String tagovi = null;

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            NewsItem newsItem = new NewsItem();
                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                            // Parsing json object response response will be a json object
                            id = person.getString("id");
                            naslov = person.getString("naslov");
                            akter = person.getString("akter");
                            akter_id = person.getString("akter_id");
                            slika = person.getString("slika");
                            izjava = person.getString("izjava");
                            izvor = person.getString("izvor");
                            datum_izjave = person.getString("datum_izjave");
                            tip_ocena = person.getString("tip_ocena");
                            kategorija = person.getString("kategorija");
                            status = person.getString("status");
                            komentar_istinomera = person.getString("komentar_istinomera");
                            tagovi = person.getString("tagovi");

                            jsonResponse += "id: " + id + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "naslov: " + naslov + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "akter: " + akter + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "akter_id: " + akter_id + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "slika: " + slika + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "izjava: " + izjava + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "izvor: " + izvor + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "datum_izjave: " + datum_izjave + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "tip_ocena: " + tip_ocena + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "kategorija: " + kategorija + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "status: " + status + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "komentar: " + komentar_istinomera + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "tagovi: " + tagovi + "\n\n";
                           /* Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + id);
                            Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + naslov);
                            Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + akter);
                            Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + akter_id);
                            Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + slika);
                            Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + izjava);
                            Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + izvor);
                            Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + datum_izjave);
                            Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + tip_ocena);
                            Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + kategorija);
                            Log.e(TAG,"JSON IS: " + status);
                            Log.e(TAG, "JSON IS: " + komentar);
                            Log.e(TAG, "JSON IS: " + tagovi);*/

                            newsItem.setIds(id);
                            newsItem.setNaslov(naslov);
                            newsItem.setAkter(akter);
                            newsItem.setAkterId(akter_id);
                            newsItem.setSlika(slika);
                            newsItem.setIzjava(izjava);
                            newsItem.setIzvor(izvor);
                            newsItem.setDatum_izjave(datum_izjave);
                            newsItem.setTip_ocena(tip_ocena);
                            newsItem.setKategorija(kategorija);
                            newsItem.setStatus(status);
                            newsItem.setKomentar_istinomera(komentar);
                            newsItem.setTagovi(tagovi);

                            newsItemList.add(newsItem);

                            //int size = newsItemList.size();
                            //Log.d("TMS", "getNaslov: " + newsItem.getNaslov() + " SIZE: " + size);

                            cdl.countDown();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("TMS", "makeJsonObjectRequest 3333 JSONException");
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.e("TMS", "makeJsonObjectRequest 44444 onErrorResponse" + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


    // Adding request to request queue
    volleyRequest.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

    try {
        cdl.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error listener prints this line:

```
Log.e("TMS", "makeJsonObjectRequest 44444 onErrorResponse" + error.getMessage());
```

> makeJsonObjectRequest 44444 onErrorResponse java.io.EOFException

and volley error log:

> E/Volley: [154] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 200 for http://www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is occurring only in rare cases, I have written code to restart my app if this error occurs.